# jQuery: Can we use it to serialize a form that returns JSON?

Tags: jquery

Can I easily use jQuery or a plugin of jQuery that serializes the data in a form as a JSON instead of  a *"text string in standard URL-encoded notation"*

ref: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: is this helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/serialize-form-to-json-with-jquery

Comment: Why do you need JSON? Maybe you mean an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Convert form data to JavaScript object with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/serialize-form-to-json-with-jquery)

The json object can then be represented as string with JSON.stringify() function. For compatibility one can use https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

Answer (score 2):

http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Answer (score 1):

```
function serializeToObject(formSerialized)
{
    return $.parseJSON("{" + formSerialized.replace(/=/g, ':').replace(/&/g, ',').replace(/([a-z]):/ig, '"$1":') + "}")
}
var object = serializeToObject($('form').serialize())
```

Comment: Nice! But I think one would also have to treat special characters that get encoded somehow, no?